# tableview has extra header when it uses auto layout in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I placed a TableView inside a Navigation Controller, which is embedded in a Tab Bar Controller. When I used auto layout for the TableView, there is always extra spaces between the top edge and the first row. Any idea why? How can I get rid of it? Thanks!

The image is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44022250/error.png).

Comment: I use storyboard to build UI completely.

Comment: The link for the image is not really working. Could you should some constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: I updated the image link. It should work now.

Comment: Do you have a view added as header view for the tableView? How is the searchBar added to the storyboard?

Comment: Hi Catalina, the search bar is added into the table view's header view. I didnt add any other view except that.

Comment: Could you check the height of the tableView header? Maybe the whole view is bigger than the search bar and there is where the extra space comes from

Answer (score 1):

try adding on viewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: This is is the answer. You can also do it in StoryBoard.